# Compare two list of string in a single iteration using C# - Unsorted list

Tags: c#, list, search

I wish to implement a Logic for Compare two List in a single iteration using C# (Un-Sorted List).

For Example:

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>() {"IOS", "Android", "Windows"};
List<string> listB = new List<string>() {"LINUS", "IOS"};
```

now I need to compare **listB** with **listA**, and I need to trace the missing items in `listB` like `"Android", "Windows"` without using C# predefined methods.

> **Note**: Iterate each list only once.

Kindly assist me.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I need a logic for `listA.Except(listB)` in an optimal way.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @IRPunch what you have tried is also correct.check my answer as an optional way.

Comment: @IRPunch iterate only one time at all or only one time each list?

Comment: @Jules - you are right. only one time each list.

Comment: Would creating two hash tables for each list then finding each item in list A in list B using the hash table solve the problem?

Comment: @TheShooter You only need to create one hash table for the comparing list, as you cannot avoid iterating through the source list.

Comment: @Abion47 Agreed. Only one hash table is required. So he can create a hash table of list B iterating it once and then can iterate list A and look up into hash table B. if the element exists it would return value else it would return null and so he would have the missing elements. This solution iterates each list only once as OP has asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely one of the most optimized answers you are likely to find:

```
public static List<T> Except<T>(List<T> a, List<T> b)
{
    var hash = new HashSet<T>(b);
    var results = new List<T>(a.Count);

    foreach (var item in a)
    {
        if (!hash.Contains(item))
        {
            results.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Rather than the `X x Y` iterations you get from comparing lists directly, you get `X + Y` - `Y` from iterating the comparison list (when converting to a hash table), and `X` for iterating over the source list (no additional `Y` since hash table lookups are constant time).

Comment: Thanks for the try. In your implementation `hash.Contains(item)` => `.Contains()` inside the `foreach` implicitly calls the `foreach` to compare (i.e., **nested foreach**)

Comment: @IRPunch No, it doesn't. `hash` is a hash table, not an iterated list, so `hash.Contains` doesn't iterate - it is a lookup function, which performs in constant time.

Comment: @IRPunch See the doc on [HashSet.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I envy you @Abion47 :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var objectList3 = listA.Where(o => !listB.Contains(o)).ToList();
```

Comment: I need a solution without any predefined method. and your answer uses 
`X x Y` iterations 
(i.e., `foreach() { foreach() {}}`)

Comment: @IRPunch It's not going to get any cheaper than that with lists.

Comment: @Abion47 - maybe but I wish to know the manual implementation, apart form the predefined extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got it completly right *(please correct me if not)*, but this could be helpful:

```
//Remove all elements of b from a 
foreach (string item in b)    
{
    a.Remove(item);
}
```

---

```
// check for all elements of a if they exist in b and store them in c if not
public static List<string> Excepts(List<string> a, List<string> b)
{
    List<string> c = new List<string>();
    foreach (string s1 in a)
    {
        bool found = false;
        foreach (string s2 in b)
        {
            if (s1 == s2)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            c.Add(s1);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your try. But in the first implementation `Remove()` inside `foreach()` => `foreach() { foreach() {}}`

Comment: In the 2nd implementation, you are explicitly using `foreach() {foreach() {}}` (i.e., X x Y iteration)

Comment: yes each list once (i.e., `listA = foreach() {}` and `listB => foreach() {}`). but in your case you implemented **nested `foreach'**.